# How to use TikTok API without a website/privacy policy url/terms of service url?

Tags: developer-tools, tiktok, tiktok-api

I'm interested in using the TikTok API in order to continue making an app that I'm building which uses social media analytics. In order to do that, the user needs to log in to their Tiktok, which needs the API for the login part and grabbing the user's data.

In order to get the API, TikTok requires you to enter a Terms of Service URL and Privacy Policy URL, however I don't have any of those...

I'm still early in development of my application, so it's all done on local host, I don't have a domain, nor do I have a clue what to write for a Terms of Service/Privacy Policy.

Is there any way to use the tiktok API to grab user data/post videos without having these requirements? Or do I really need to make a website, terms or service and a privacy policy deploy it then test it. I feel like there should be a way to actually use the API locally to test it and see how it works before having an actual app live.

Thanks in advance.

This feels like a common conern however I can't find the answer to this anywhere, even in tutorials they just say "yeah enter your url for your website and so on"... Well my website would be based on data provided by the TikTok API, so I can't really have anything on my website yet. It makes no sense to deploy my website THEN test the API locally

Comment: Put together a really basic little website with a really basic little terms of service and privacy policy. Crib off other sites; https://commonpaper.com/standards/ has some pre-made policies for this purpose.